# Automated alert if inbox count exceeds certain limit

Tags: alert, inbox, unread-mail

I have various mailboxes configured and I would like to setup an alert if the unread count in the inbox of a particular mailbox exceeds a certain limit.

Ideally an email that comes to the inbox is moved to another folder by an emailImporter service. We have had several occurrences where the service went down and the Inbox count grew.

So, to determine if the service is up/down, I want to setup an alert on the server if the inbox count is greater than 15, then notify the support teams.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: And which e-mail product are you using, i.e. where is this inbox?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am using MS Outlook, but I wont have it open for all the time. So, is there a way I could set up an alert that will run without me having to open Outlook all the time?

Comment: And are you using outlook to connect to a company Exchange server, or to an Internet POP3 mailbox, or something else?  Maybe you could add more detail to your question to help people help you.

Comment: Yes I use Outlook to connect to a company exchange server. I am sorry for missing such information on my question.

Comment: I am looking for the same exact solution. I haven't found yet an already developed solution, so I am starting to think in scheduled task + powershell (get-mailboxstatistics).